# When i insert multiple images to mysql it's responses phpEEE4.tmp does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

Hi i am new to laravel trying to do some product information like online shop. The problem is when i insert multiple images it's returns "The file "C:\xampp\tmp\phpEEE4.tmp" does not exist".

Here is input code: `<input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple>`
Here is DB code :

```
DB::table('laravel_products')
                 ->insert( array(
                     'name' => $name,
                     'price' => $price,
                     'qty' => $qty,
                     'description' => $description,
                     'uruu' => $uruu,
                     'garage' => $garage,
                     'duureg' => $duureg,
                     'tagt' => $tagt,
                     'talbai' => $talbai,
                     'haalga' => $haalga,
                     'tsonh' => $tsonh,
                     'shal' => $shal,
                     'tsonhtoo' => $ttsonh,
                     'hdawhar' => $bdawhar,
                     'lizing' => $lizing,
                     'utas' => $utas,
                     'email' => $email,
                     'hereg' => $hereg,
                     'bairshil' => $bairshil,
                     'bairlal' => $bairlal,
                     'ashig' => $ashigon,
                     'zahi' => $zahi,
                     'image' => $data
                     )
                 );
                $lastInsertedID = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
                $image = array();
if($files = $Request->file('file')){
    foreach ($files as $file){
        $image_name = md5(rand(1000,10000));
        $ext = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $image_full_name = $image_name.'.'.$ext;
        $upload_path = 'uploads/';
        $image_url = $upload_path.$image_full_name;
        $file->move($upload_path, $image_full_name);
        $image[] = $image_url;
    }
}
        DB::insert('laravel_products_images')->insert(array('product_id'=> $lastInsertedID,'filename'=> implode('|',$image)));
            return view('createproduct');
```

}
}
Have you guys experienced things like this ? If yes How do i fix ? and is there any problem in code? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to read [laravel file upload section](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads) and use laravel way for storing file.

Comment: did you end up using `lastInsertId` or `insertGetId` ?

Comment: i used lastInsertId to get.